# mapping error in AS400 CL Declare/Receive (DCLF RCVF)?

Tags: ibm-midrange

mapping error in AS400 CL

I am trying to get value of fields on record where 'MYVALUE' is first key on DDS LF MYVIEW. I get mapping error. I suspect that this is because the field is defined as VARLEN ( 255A  +  VARLEN).  Do I have a work around?

```
DCLF       FILE(MYVIEW)                                            
DCL        VAR(&FIELD) TYPE(*CHAR) STG(*AUTO) LEN(255) +               
              VALUE('MYVALUE')                                         
OVRDBF     FILE(MYVIEW) POSITION(*KEY 1 *N &FIELD)                 
RCVF                        

 Erreur de mappage de données sur DT44SRVREQ.  (CPF5035, CPF5097)
 14 - La longueur d'une zone de longueur variable, ou les données d'une   
variable de sous-chaîne sont incorrectes.     


 Field              File             Type                  Length 
 CODERAPP44         MYVIEW            VARCHAR                 255
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best workaround would be to choose to do it with RPGLE but you can do it like this :

```
   DCLF       FILE(MYVIEW)

   dcl        &key *char 257
   dcl        &key_length *int 2 stg(*defined) defvar(&key 1)
   dcl        &key_value *char 255 stg(*defined) defvar(&key 3)

   chgvar     &key_value 'MYKEY'
   chgvar     &key_length (%checkr(' ' &key_value))

   OVRDBF     FILE(MYVIEW) POSITION(*KEY 1 *N &key)
   RCVF
```